# Correlation between large number of variables

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with 30 variables and I want to see what variables among them are correlating. I have used df.corr() but the result seems difficult to understand as it contains a large matrix.

Is there any way to build a heat map out of this or to get the correlation pairs with coefficient of correlation greater than or less than some fixed value(for e.g.- r < -0.8 & r > 0.8)?

Comment: Your question will probably get flagged unless you can be a little more specific about what a helpful output would be.  Would you like a heatmap, or maybe to return only the highest _n_ correlation pairs, etc?  Try to make it more direct instead of asking for subjective suggestions.

Comment: I suggest deleting your question and asking again in a clearer fashion.

Comment: depend what you want, you can try to correlate each variable to each other one... or reduce dimension using PCA or autoencoder...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The seaborn package has an excellent function to create heatmaps. http://seaborn.pydata.org/index.html

The following is a piece of example code that yields a heatmap of a correlation matrix.

```
df= pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,4,[72,5]))
df.columns = ['col1','col2','col3','col4','col5']
import seaborn as sns
sns.heatmap(df.corr())
plt.yticks(rotation= 0)
plt.xticks(rotation=90)
```

[image]